# WFS Mapguide Maestro. Can't query features?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, mapguide

I'm using MapGuide Maestro 5.0 and Geoserver 2.4.0.

I have added a new WFS feature source to the viewer, and used the following url:

```
 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/scotwat/wfs?
```

In the vector layer def it shows the fields and these have been checked to be visible.

The viewer shows the features, but when I click on them to select, nothing happens. I have looked through the Properties of both the feature and layer, and cannot find an option to turn it on. I have also ensured that the box 'Features on the layer are selectable (if visible)' is checked. I also added the wfs to qgis, and can select features through there.

EDIT: I have progressed slightly, but am still stuck. The problem lies with the primary key of the WFS service. Within geoserver the option 'Expose primary key' is checked. MapGuide produces the following warning the feature source is validated:

```
 No primary key defined for class: scotwat:paris_hetero, features will not be selectable and feature joins on this class may produce unexpected results
```

The data source the WFS is generated has a primary key, but this has not been seen by MapGuide Maestro. Any help? If I know what the primary key how can I define it in MapGuide Maestro?